# Are agricultural pilots allowed to use a highway as a runway?

Tags: faa-regulations

I lived not far from a spray pilot who had had a hangar in his yard in the country but right off the highway. Would he need some special endorsement to use the highway as a runway?

Comment: While not strictly against FAA regulations, local ordinances would probably be the controlling factor here. The other problem is making sure that it is safe to use (people, cars, power lines, power poles, mailboxes, etc). There is no special endorsement for using the highway as far as the FAA is concerned.

Comment: Perhaps doesn't apply now, but back in the 1950s my father was an agricultural pilot, and I remember him using country gravel roads on occasion. I don't recall him ever using a paved road,

Comment: [This question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/7687/62) is very closely related, perhaps even a dupe. Essentially, the FAA doesn't care very much about where you take off and land - as long as you do it safely! - but the landowner/county/state often does. So the limiting factor is local land zoning and other laws, not FAA regulations.

Comment: ok thank you for the answers

Comment: There are many highway segments that are on purpose designed to be usable as runways [list here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Highway_strip). But this is more for the military.

Answer (score 2):

My answer is colored by having spent a couple of years as an ag applicator.

There is no endorsement needed to use the highway as a runway.

Practically, it is done less now than 30 years ago.  Also more states have codes now which prohibit operating aircraft off public highways.

Locally an operator used a paved road which terminated at an interstate, where all the houses on that road were owned by the same family. In 1978 that operator had to scramble, because the town decided to enforce a code prohibiting aircraft from using town roads for landing and takeoff.  The only other place I have seen it today is in parts of the northern mid-West. I am not familiar with their local codes or state codes.